# Find a line without a keyword / in given pairs of lines

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Trying to filter a firewall security policy which doesn't have log enabled.

I just GREPed the policy which provides the output of policies matching "both action and log settings". But I dont know any filtering mechanisms.

```
#zcat config.gz | egrep permit\|deny\|log | grep policy 
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 44 then permit  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 44 then log session-init  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 34 then permit  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 34 then log session-init  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 82 then permit  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 82 then log session-init  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 82 then log session-close  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 73 then deny  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 73 then log session-close  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 72 then deny  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 72 then log session-close  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 67 then permit  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 53 then permit  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 53 then log session-init  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 30 then deny  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 30 then log session-close  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 75 then permit  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 75 then log session-init  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 76 then permit  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 28 then permit  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 28 then log session-init  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 50 then permit  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 50 then log session-init  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 51 then permit  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 51 then log session-init  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 55 then permit  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 55 then log session-init  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 56 then permit  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 79 then permit  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 79 then log session-init  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 57 then permit  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 57 then log session-init  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 58 then permit  
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 58 then log session-init
```

I would like to know the policies which doesn't have log enabled.

Example: 
'policy 67' have only permit statement but not logged. 
The policy name should be filtered out and displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk, in a single call:

```
zcat config.gz | awk '
$8 == "policy" {
  if ($11 ~ /permit|deny/ && !($9 in log_enabled))
    policies[$9]
  else if ($11 == "log") {
    log_enabled[$9]
    delete policies[$9]
  }
}
END {
  for (policy in policies)
      print "policy", policy
}'
```

If there **must** be at least one **action** per policy, it gets easier:

```
zcat config.gz | awk '
/policy.*(permit|deny|log)/ {
  policies[$9]++
}
END {
  for (policy in policies)
    if (policies[policy] == 1)
      print "policy", policy
}'
```

Comment: It would be good to acknowledge that your (second) solution is partly based on mine, because otherwise it looks like I copied yours.

Comment: @Alex I edited my answer after you posted yours. So it doesn't look like you copied mine. Even if you'd done that it wouldn't be a problem

Comment: Fair enough. I would have added a note, "After seeing X's answer, note that ..." No big deal.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk for true multi-dimensional arrays:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/permit|deny|log/ && /policy/ { present[$9][$11] }
END {
    for (policy in present) {
        if ( !( "log" in present[policy] ) ) {
            print policy
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
56
67
76
```

With any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/permit|deny|log/ && /policy/ { policies[$9]; present[$9,$11] }
END {
    for (policy in policies) {
        if ( !( (policy,"log") in present ) ) {
            print policy
        }
    }
}
```

With the above approach you can write `if` statements to test whatever combinations of states you like for each policy.

Comment: Interesting feature of GNU AWK.

Comment: @AlexHarvey Yes, it has many including sorted "in", indirect function calls, time functions, open file handling, IGNORECASE, FPAT, BEGINFILE/ENDFILE, isarray(), typeof(), gensub(), 3rd arg to match() to save capture groups, 4th arg to split() to save separators, FIELDWIDTHS, SYMTAB, etc., etc. Everyone should really get GNU awk if at all possible!

Answer (score 0):

It's not so easy with `awk`/`sed` because the problem requires looking at multiple lines. One solution could be:

```
sort -n -k9,9 stackoverflow55844671.txt | \
    awk '{if(prev==$9){
            logged += ($0 ~ / log /)
          }else{
            if(logged==0){print prev};
            prev=$9;
            logged=($0 ~ / log /)
          }
        }END{if(logged==0){print prev}}'
```

First it sorts together the lines based on the policy number (9th field), then the awk part processes each line, but stores the value of the policy and the output of the pattern matching (feel free to modify the regular expression).

This gives me:

```
56
67
76
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.(not hard-coded fields values for string policy)

```
awk '
match($0,/policy [0-9]+/){
  if(($NF=="permit" || $NF=="deny")|| ($(NF-1)=="log" && $NF~/session/)){
     a[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]++
  }
}
END{
  for(i in a){
     if(a[i]<2){
       print i,a[i]
     }
  }
}
'   Input_file
```

You could remove `a[i]` which gives its occurrence's total from above code in `END` block of `awk` in case you don't need it too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an AWK solution:

```awk
/policy.*(permit|deny|log)/ {
  policy = $0
  gsub(/.*then /, "", policy)
  ar[$9] = ar[$9] " " policy
}
END {
  for (key in ar)
    if (ar[key] !~ /log/)
      print "policy", key, ar[key]
}
```

Testing:

```
$ awk -f test.awk <<< $data
policy 56  permit
policy 76  permit
policy 67  permit
```

Note that this solution has the advantage of reporting both the policy numbers and the details of the policies.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may prefer a two-pass solution:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {if (/then log/) logging[$9]; next} 
       /then (permit|deny)/ && !($9 in logging)' file file

set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 67 then permit
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 76 then permit
set security policies from-zone Trust to-zone Untrust policy 56 then permit
```

Or if you just want to print part of the line:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {if (/then log/) logging[$9]; next} 
       /then (permit|deny)/ && !($9 in logging) {print $8,$9}' file file

policy 67
policy 76
policy 56
```